# configuration error in RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm, ruby-1.9.3

I am trying to download ruby 1.9.3 (for learning purposes, this is the version in the book)
When I run `$rvm install 1.9.3` I get a configuration error:

> Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.6:/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.3.3:/usr/local/Cellar/libksba/1.3.0:/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
>   showing last 15 lines of /Users/john/.rvm/log/1398181983_ruby-1.9.3-p545/configure.log

Then the last 15 lines are:

```
[2014-04-22 10:53:15] ./configure
current path: /Users/john/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p545
PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.28/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/libtool/2.4.2/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/automake/1.14.1/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.69/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/john/.rvm/bin:/Users/john/.rvm/bin
command(7): ./configure --prefix=/Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.6:/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.3.3:/usr/local/Cellar/libksba/1.3.0:/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.1g --without-tcl --without-tk --disable-install-doc --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.1.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.1.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin13.1.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/john/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p545':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Does anyone know what is wrong here?  Since I'm new, I'm assuming it is something simple...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables when installing Ruby 1.9.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872796/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables-when-installing-ruby-1-9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is with the c compliers. You should be doing

> sudo apt-get install clang && rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang